# can a request directly come to ejb container or it should first come to web container.can anyone please explain?

Tags: java, ejb, websphere

> can a request directly come to ejb container or it should first come to web >container and hit ejb?can anyone please explain?
>
> I want to know the runtime flow of the application in middleware server

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in two cases:

- A session bean exposes a remote interface.  In this case, a client can directly invoke the EJB.
- A message-driven bean is configured, and a message is sent that it is listening for.

There are a few additional cases where the EJB can get control without any request:

- A singleton session bean is annotated (or configured via XML) to be `@Startup` and defines a PostConstruct method.  In this case, the bean will get control when the application is deployed.
- A session bean is annotated (or configured via XML) to be `@Schedule`.  In this case, the bean will get control at the specified time.

In all other cases, another component (e.g., a servlet) must get control first and invoke the EJB.